Get a String using "case" when my query is empty on oracle or just the list of element?
Good morning i have a simple question to do:
Updated
I have to do a select to get if there are records where length are different than a number. I know that my result could be some records or just no result because will be empty, this is my query:
select CASE WHEN id IS null THEN 'no existen' ELSE ID END AS existen
from dvd.cicle 
WHERE LENGTH(ID) <> (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ID)) FROM dvd.cicle )

but my result looks like this:

i need to get as result just the text "no existen" if the result is empty or the ID's if the query give me something different as the max/length. Can somebody help me?
Regards

Please share your schema as well

You can use a subquery to sort the id's in your table by their length. And you need to select something from dual if your table doesn't contain id's with different lengths.
Then combine the results using UNION ALL.
Use NOT EXISTS to make sure that your "fallback string" will be selected only if the list of id's of the main query is empty.
Something like this:
WITH sorted AS
  (SELECT  
    id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(id) DESC) AS ranking
   FROM cicle)
 SELECT id AS existen FROM sorted WHERE ranking > 1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'not exists' FROM dual
 WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM sorted WHERE ranking > 1);

This will return the list of id's except for those having the greatest length if id's with different lengths exist. And it will return not exists otherwise.
Note: In Oracle23c, you can remove the FROM dual.
See this sample fiddle

Hello @Jonas, thanks for the answer it helps me a lot. Just one point about te query: How i will show intead of "not exists" the list of ID's ? - Regards

And you are setting the number 5 as max length... I'm using the function max/length because i don't want to set manually in this case the number "5" - Regards

@Julio I updated my answer according to your new question. Could you please check if it works as you expect?

You can do it only querying the table once using:
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN LENGTH(id) = MAX(LENGTH(id)) OVER ()
         THEN NULL
         ELSE id
         END as id,
         1 AS priority
  FROM   dvd.cicle
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'no existen',
         2
  FROM   DUAL
)
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY priority
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE dvd.cicle (id VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO dvd.cicle (id) VALUES ('XXXXX');

Outputs:



ID




no existen



And if you insert extra, shorter, IDs:
INSERT INTO dvd.cicle (id)
SELECT 'AAAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E' FROM DUAL;

The query then outputs:



ID




AAAA


BBBB


CCC


DD


E



fiddle

If you want to handle NULL values as zero-length strings then:
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT id, 1 AS priority
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(id) DESC NULLS LAST) as rnk
    FROM   dvd.cicle
  )
  WHERE  rnk > 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'no existen',
         2
  FROM   DUAL
)
ORDER BY priority
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;

fiddle
